# Creating a csv file on an Azure File share from a list that was created in a C# Azure Function

Tags: azure

I have an application that creates a list from a call to an API. The list is basically a class the contains information about a golf tournament.
This is the class:

```
public class Output
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string TournamentName { get; set; }
    public string TournamentPermId { get; set; }
    public string PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int RoundNumber { get; set; }
    public int CourseNumber { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string TeeTme { get; set; }
    public int HoleNumber { get; set; }
    public int HoleScore { get; set; }
    public int ParValue { get; set; }
    public int Yardage { get; set; }
    public string DrivingDistanceMeasured { get; set; }
    public int DrivingDistance { get; set; }

 }
```

What I am currently doing is creating a csv file and saving it to a local directory. No problem.
What I would like to do is to save it to an Azure file share. I have no problem writing the file to the Azure File Share once it is created locally. Works fine.

What I am trying to do now is to run this process as an Azure Function that runs on a timer (once a week). The function works fine, it creates the list as it should from the API. But now I want to write the output to the Azure Share directly from the Azure Function. Since there is no file to copy, I need to create a new file directly from the list and save it to the share.

I define the following variables for my share:

```
    var connectionString = "MyConnectionString";
    var fileShareName = "MyShare";
    var folderName = "MyDate\\2022 data";
    var fileName = "Testfile.csv";
```

My list is called Outputs.

When I stream it to the azure file share from the local file I do it this way:

```
    var localFilePath = @"c:\temp\Testfile.csv";  
    ShareClient share = new(connectionString, fileShareName);  
    var directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(folderName);  
    var file = directory.GetFileClient(fileName);  
    using FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);  
    file.Create(stream.Length);  
    file.UploadRange(  
        new HttpRange(0, stream.Length),  
        stream);
```

That works fine.

What I can't figure out is how to stream my list, Outputs, into a new file on the file share.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this?

This is how I create the csv file in the desktop app (outputs is the list):

```
    private void CreateCsvFile()
    {
        string Path = @"c:\technical\";
        string file = _currentTournName.Replace(" ", String.Empty);

        fileName = Path + file + ".csv";
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            Delimiter = ";",
        };
        using (var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamwriter, config))
            {

                csvWriter.WriteRecords(outputs);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include how are you creating the CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this problem by just using temp storage in azure. I created my csv file in temp storage then I streamed it to the file share.